# Error when uploading to iTunesConnect

Tags: air, app-store-connect, application-loader

I am using Application Loader to upload my .ipa files (created with Adobe AIR v18) to iTunesConnect.

It's been working fine for months, but today I received two new errors:

```
The u option must have a non-empty value.
The password must have a non-empty value.
```

Can anyone shed some light on the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 2 solutions:

1) Update your Xcode to 7.1 (but since you are not coding natively, use the solution #2 below)

or

2) Download and use the Application Loader v3.1 (Download link: https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/tools  ) to submit your IPA

Answer (score 7):

I upgraded to Xcode 7.1 and that solved the problem!

Note: Xcode 7.1 comes with Application Loader 3.3.

Comment: I know "thanks" comments aren't appreciated, but THANKS

Answer (score 5):

Apart from *low-belly*'s answer you can try to use XCode's built-in upload feature. If you go to the Organizer, just click on `Upload to App Store`:

[image]

This solved the problem for me in XCode 7.0.1.

Comment: Works for me too. Under Xcode 7.0.1, Application Loader is broken, but loading through the Organizer directly to the AppStore works.

Comment: Same here, I uploaded the app using the Xcode Organizer, Application Loader fails validating the archive.

Comment: Thanks for this nice suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 7.1 was downloading too slow (more than 4GB) and the update failed every time, so for now I downloaded the Application Loader 3.1 from iTunes Connect and it worked fine.

To download it you login into iTunes Connect -> Resources and Help -> click on View Tools (under the title Other Resources at the bottom of the page) and there is the download link.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error last night.  Fixed it by signing out of Application Loader (3.6) and logging back in.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with Application Loader 3.2. Submitting with Application Loader **3.0** (bundled with Xcode 6.2) or **3.1** (bundled with Xcode 6.4) solved the problem.